# Как в диалоговое окно вывести массив элементов?

Tags: javascript, html

Как в диалоговое окно вывести массив элементов?

```js
function addFile(){
  var res = [] ;
  var kol = 0;
  var ui = [] ;
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles() ;
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var fname = file.getName();
        res.push(file.getName());
        kol++
      }
    for(var i = 0 ; i < kol ; i++){
      ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<li style = "list-style-type: none"><input type="checkbox" >'+ res[i] + '</li><br>') ;
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Add the file") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ui.push(HtmlService.create...);
```

---

```
var ui = "";
for(var i = 0 ; i < kol ; i++){
  ui += '<li style = "list-style-type: none"><input type="checkbox" >'+ res[i] + '</li><br>' ;
}
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(ui,"Add the file"),
  "Add the file"
);
```

Comment: вроде бы ,всё верно и на выводе ui ,показывает ,что в массиве все элементы ,но почему-то не запускается диалоговое окно ,хотя перед этим работало ,в чем может быть проблема ?